# Sidenavigation. Load everything with one request or splitted?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, asynchronous, navigation

i use a sidepanel to navigate through the webapps settings.

Simple Schema like:

```
TopEntry1
->Sub 1
->Sub 2
->Sub 3

TopEntry2
->Sub 1
->Sub 2

...
```

At the moment i have two options in use. Depending on the top menus classes the app loads all subchoices with a click on the top entry and shows/hides the containers with a click on the subentry.

The second option loads the selected part after the subentry is clicked.

Now I see that this maybe isn't a good choice. Every click on such a sub entry generates a request.

Is it better to load it all one time with a click on the top entry and hide/show containers with a click on the subs? This produces some more complex queries but executes them only once. The other way produces simple queries but runs them with every click which results in many small queries if users play around with the menu.

Whats your opinion?

The possibility of several small queries or a single bigger query that produces output that, maybe, isn't needed?